# About using range based for loop over a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, range

I am working on some graph problem.  I have:

```
vector<vector<int>> e
```

that I populate as:

```cpp
for(vector<int> edge: edges) {
    e[edge[0]].push_back(edge[1]);
    e[edge[1]].push_back(edge[0]);
}
```

Now when I try to access `e` using a range based for loop like:

```
for(vector<int> v: e[node])
```

I get an error:

> no viable conversion from `int` to `vector<int>`

Which I guess means I should use:

```
for(int i: e[node])
```

How - isn't each element of `e` a vector?

Comment: Open ended - sometimes I find it difficult to visualize complex data-structures like vector of unordered_maps, etc.  Any resources that would teach me to visualize them?

Comment: You're not iterating over `e`, you're iterating over one element of `e` (a vector), and each element of that element of `e` is an `int`.

Comment: Yes, so each element of `e` is a vector, so shouldn't I have to use `vector<int>` instead of  just `int`?

Comment: Teachyou to visualize, I dunno. I just use a pencil (a 0.5mm Papermate G-Force) and paper (no special requirements).

Comment: @J.Doe you are trying to iterate within `e[node]`, not `e`.

Comment: `for (const std::vector<int>& edge : edges)`or `for (const auto& edge : edges)` would avoid unnecessary copies over your `for(vector<int> edge : edges)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each element of e is a vector, each element of e[node] is int.